# R xgboost package parameters relation

Tags: r, xgboost

After reading the docs, it's not 100% clear to me the difference and the relation between the parameters `eval_metric`, `maximize` e `feval`.

For example, while doing linear regression, i'm setting `eval_metric` to a custom kappa function, then `maximize` = TRUE. What's the difference between `eval_metric` and `feval`?

Thanks!

Comment: By now i'm guessing they are the same thing, but not sure yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to answer my own question: `feval` and `eval_metric` are the same thing. The same applies to `obj` and `objective`. It's all on github repo: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.